# Cannot resolve symbol 'Gamepanel'

Tags: java, resolve, cannot-find-symbol

i had this problem with this code and it got the error "Cannot resolve symbol 'Gamepanel'"

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class GameFrame extends JFrame{


    GameFrame(){
        GamePanel panel;
        panel = new Gamepanel();
        this.add(panel);
        this.setTitle("Pong Game");

    }
}
```

can someone help me, please?

Comment: Your class is either GamePanel or Gamepanel.  It cannot be spelled both ways.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you variable panel is from the type GamePanel.
Therefore, when you assign panel an Instance, you have to write the classname correct:

```
GamePanel panel;
panel = new GamePanel(); // GamePanel not Gamepanel
```